# Does Paperclip automatically clean up filenames?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using Thoughtbot's [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle file uploads.

I'm finding that when I upload a file with spaces in the filename, it gets stored with the spaces replaced with underscores.

That's good.

I also tried uploading a file with special characters like `~` and so on and they all got replaced with underscores.

Great. Exactly what I want.

But why is it happening?

All I'm doing in my model is...

```
has_attached_file(
    file_somefile,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/other/path/elements/:basename.:extension"
)
```

Is this Paperclip's default behavior?

Comment: What OS? On OS X I get filenames w/ the original spaces and tildes.

Comment: I'm using OS X, Paperclip 2.3.1.1

Comment: Hmm. I don't explicitly set the path in the app I tested this against, other than that, I'm not doing anything either. Can't check my version at the moment, but I didn't specify the version in the Gemfile, so probably 2.4.1ish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, after a little more searching, I found [this blog post](http://www.davesouth.org/stories/make-url-friendly-filenames-in-paperclip-attachments) that says, down at the bottom, that Paperclip actually does some minimal processing of filenames.

Answer (score 16):

To add a little more information, this happens in [Paperclip::Attachment#cleanup_filename](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L475) in which the default restricted_characters /[&$+,/:;=?@<>[]{}\|\\^~%# ]/ are replaced with underscores.

It's not documented, but you can specify the :restricted_characters option to paperclip to change what gets replaced, e.g.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :restricted_characters => /@/ # only replaces '@'
end
```

Comment: Update link to [Paperclip::Attachment#cleanup_filename](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L605)