# How to handle filenames with non-alphanumeric characters with Rails Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, paperclip

I'm using Rails 3 with Paperclip + Rails:

```
Gemfile
  gem "paperclip"
  gem "mongoid-paperclip", require: 'mongoid_paperclip'
```

Everything works fine unless a user uploads a photo with a filename with non-alphanumeric characters like so:

```
thing 1/2/3/.PNG
```

I've tried handling this with `before_post_process` `before_validation` :

```
  def strip_strange_characters_from_attachments
    # Set the clean Attachment File Title
    self.attachment.instance.meta['file_name'] = "test.png"
  end
```

However Rails is erring beforehand and files are not uploading. Error below. Any ideas?

```
[2014-06-10 13:54:47] INFO    Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG[0]'
[2014-06-10 13:54:47] INFO    [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[2014-06-10 13:54:47] INFO    Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG[0]'
[2014-06-10 13:54:47] INFO    [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[2014-06-10 13:54:47] INFO    Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG[0]'
[2014-06-10 13:54:47] INFO    Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 120.0ms
[2014-06-10 13:54:48] INFO    Mongo: (1.5333ms) | Query count: 3
[2014-06-10 13:54:48] FATAL   
Mongoid::Errors::Validations - 
Problem:
  Validation of Mongo::Attachment failed.
Summary:
  The following errors were found: Attachment /var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG is not recognized by the 'identify' command., Attachment /var/folders/g_/kythn1dx4fbbry5npb4jx1cr0000gn/T/thing 1:2:3:20140610-41978-ksy5e9.PNG is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Resolution:
```

Any ideas / suggestions on handling this error?

Comment: What's your version of paperclip? The newer ones have a `cleanup_filename` method in there by default to deal with this. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328423/does-paperclip-automatically-clean-up-filenames).

Comment: It appears that the mongo paperclip gem doesn't support cleanup_filename - https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip/search?q=restricted_characters

Comment: May be use obfuscation? https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#uri-obfuscation

Comment: Thanks but obfuscating filenames isn't good as the end user won't be happy with download filenames they don't recognize.

Comment: But original file name stored in the database, or you do not provide information from db for users?

Answer (score 7):

The mongoid-paperclip gem just hands down all given options to paperclip (see [source](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip/blob/master/lib/mongoid_paperclip.rb#L103)) so you need to clean the filename, just like you would when using plain paperclip.

There are two options to accomplish this, and here are the default values:

```
 :restricted_characters => /[&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/, 
 :filename_cleaner => nil,
```

Normally whitespace is perfectly fine in a filename, but you could try to add it to the `:restricted_characters`. The restricted-characters are used to initialise a `PaperClip::FilenameCleaner`.

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image, restricted_characters: /[\s&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/
```

You could be more explicit and specify a filename cleaner as follows (but not sure if that is relevant).

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :image, filename_cleaner: Paperclip::FilenameCleaner.new(/[\s&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/)
```

This is exactly the same as specifying the `restricted_characters` option. However, you could use this option and hand it your own version of a `FilenameClear`. It should have a `call` method and will receive the filename as parameter (see [source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/65cc5c7d4ffd4d015be202d807220d2acd5d1f93/lib/paperclip/filename_cleaner.rb))

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error you're getting, it appears that the filename **is** getting fixed. The `/`'s are being replaced with `:`'s.

Doing some searching around, and it looks like the most common cause for that error is Paperclip not being able to find ImageMagick. Setting `Paperclip.options[:command_path]` should fix that. It can also be caused by various gem version mismatches.

Take a look at [rails paperclip and passenger `is not recognized by the 'identify' command`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996102/rails-paperclip-and-passenger-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command) for a bunch of (hopefully) helpful things to try.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar and handled it with before_create and before_update, but this was with the regular Paperclip gem.  The randomize_file_name method isn't shown, but you get the idea.

```
before_create :randomize_attachment_name
before_update :randomize_attachment_name

def randomize_attachment_name
  if document_file_name
    random_name = randomize_file_name(document_file_name)
    self.document.instance_write(:file_name, random_name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just change path with something like this ?

```
path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:id.:extension'
```